# Showing $|I(\lambda)|\le C\lambda^{-N}$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

> Let $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $I(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{i\lambda\phi(\xi)}a(\xi)d\xi$, where $a\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, and assume $D\phi$ does not vanish on the support of $a$ then $\exists C=C(a,\phi,N)$ such that, $$|I(\lambda)|\le C\lambda^{-N},\quad \lambda\to\infty$$ for every $N\ge1$

I don't understand the problem here, since $e^{i\dots}$ is in general bounded and $a$ has compact support, the integral should be then bounded, what is the conclusion here, that the integral must be equal to 0 ?

Comment: The function $a(\xi)$ is smooth and you have uniform bounds on the derivatives, so you can control its oscillations. On the other hand, the exponential is an oscillating function of zero mean and the oscillations get finer and finer when $ \lambda$ tends to infinity. The asymptotic begaviour is a result of cancellations in an oscillating integrand

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Sorry I forgot that part, edited now